# Why websocket working with ws but not with wss

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, websocket

i have websocket ( ratchet ) running. And create a javascript client for testing.

its working with below url

ws://ip:8888/ws

But not with

wss://ip:8888/wss

May i know where i need to change. And also it would be helpfull httpd.conf configuration in-order to work webseocket with ws and wss.
My instance is behind AWS ELB and configured ssl( tcp) and tcp portocol.

Answer (score 0):

[Classic] Elastic Load Balancer does not support WSS. You should use the new type of Load Balancer called *Application Load Balancer*, which support  WebSockets natively, including SSL.

> Application Load Balancers provide native support for Websockets. You
>   can use WebSockets with both HTTP and HTTPS listeners.
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html